# Improve performance on LINQ Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

My linq query goes slow when I try to loop through the results to create an Xelement, which I later process XSLT based on the XElement.

Here is my code

```
public override XElement Search(SearchCriteria searchCriteria)
    {
        XElement root = new XElement("Root");
        using (ReportOrderLogsDataContext dataContext = DataConnection.GetLinqDataConnection<ReportOrderLogsDataContext>(searchCriteria.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            try
            {


                IQueryable<vw_udisclosedDriverResponsePart> results = from a in dataContext.vw_udisclosedDriverResponseParts
                              where
                                  (a.CreateDt.HasValue &&
                                   a.CreateDt >= Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.BeginDt) &&
                                   a.CreateDt <= Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.EndDt))
                              select a;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.AgentNumber))
                {
                    results = results.Where(request => request.LgAgentNumber == searchCriteria.AgentNumber);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.AgentTitle))
                {
                    results = results.Where(a => a.LgTitle == searchCriteria.AgentTitle);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.QuotePolicyNumber))
                {
                    results = results.Where(a => a.QuotePolicyNumber == searchCriteria.QuotePolicyNumber);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.InsuredName))
                {
                    results = results.Where(a => a.LgInsuredName.Contains(searchCriteria.InsuredName));
                }

                foreach (var match in results) // goes slow here, specifically times out before evaluating the first match when results are too large.
                {
                    DateTime date;
                    string strDate = string.Empty;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(match.CreateDt.ToString(), out date))
                    {
                        strDate = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    }

                    root.Add(new XElement("Record",
                                          new XElement("System", "Not Supported"),
                                          new XElement("Date", strDate),
                                          new XElement("Agent", match.LgAgentNumber),
                                          new XElement("UserId", match.LgUserId),
                                          new XElement("UserTitle", match.LgTitle),
                                          new XElement("QuoteNum", match.QuotePolicyNumber),
                                          new XElement("AddressLine1", match.AddressLine1),
                                          new XElement("AddressLine2", match.AddressLine2),
                                          new XElement("City", match.City),
                                          new XElement("State", match.State),
                                          new XElement("Zip", match.Zip),
                                          new XElement("DriverName", string.Concat(match.GivenName, " ", match.SurName)),
                                          new XElement("DriverLicense", match.LicenseNumber),
                                          new XElement("LicenseState", match.LicenseState)));
                    ;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {

                throw es;
            }
        }
        return root;
        // return GetSearchedCriteriaFromStoredPocedure(searchCriteria);
    }
```

I assume there is a better way to convert the results object into an XElement. Processing the view itself only takes about 2 seconds. Trying to loop through the results object is resulting in a timeout, even when many results are not returned.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

-James

AMENDED 7/10/2012

The issue is not with the linq query itself but its with the execution of the view when specifying a date range. Executing the view by itself takes about 4-6 seconds. When a small date range (07/05/2012 - 07/10/2012) is used the view takes around 1:30. Does anyone have any suggestions of how to increase performance of the query with a date range specified. Its faster if I got all of the results and looped through them checking the date.

i.e.

```
    IQueryable<vw_udisclosedDriverResponsePart> results = from a in dataContext.vw_udisclosedDriverResponseParts select a;

                foreach (var match in results) //results only takes 3 seconds to enumerate, before would timeout
                {
                    // eval search criteria date here.
                }
```

I can code it like I suggested above, but does anyone have a better way?

Comment: Does the query always run too slowly, or only when you specify a certain combination of query criteria? For instance, when you specify only the `searchCriteria.AgentNumber` and leave everything else blank, is your query still too slow?

Comment: When you're using LINQ, the query isn't executed until you enumerate the results, so probably the execution of the query is what's taking so long, not the creation of the XElements.

Comment: Not enough info here. You can use profiler tool like DotTrace (you don't have to wait until it finishes, just wait couple of minutes and get snapshot). It will show you where you are losing time - in the database, in the garbage collector, in XElement creation or maybe in DataTime parsing. If it is database, then maybe you should use direct SQL or maybe you should generate XML on server in the stored procedure.

Comment: ditto on Daniel's comment.  Linq looks really pretty, its easy to read, and easy to write.  Unfortunately, because of the way the execution time tends to run, you might end up shooting yourself in the foot by looping nested linq queries.  Especially when if one query references another.  Try to follow your actual execution steps by stepping into the loop or putting a breakpoint inside the linq statements.  you might be surprised with how many extra steps are being taken that you wouldn't normally expect.

Comment: I specified no other search criteria accept the dates. 7/5/2012 - 7/9/2012. The date ranges specified should onyl return about 300 rows of data. I have a similar LINQ query for another view that returns thousands of rows that goes really quick. Perhaps I should use "var Results" instead of  IQueryable<vw_udisclosedDriverResponsePart> and only return the columns I need. Thanks for the input guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does the database perform? The simplest test is to run a sample query - a query that will retrieve the data you need from the database, just to test database indexing and performance - because in 99% of cases that's the cause of slowness.

I would guess that the slowness is occurring because

- you are iterating from the database, rather than retrieving all the rows up front, and
- you are selecting on bad `WHERE` conditions (are your indexes correct?)

Firstly, call `ToList` to get the results to determine that the slowness is happening in the database, not in the XML construction

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.InsuredName))
{
    //...
}    
var matches = results.ToList();    
foreach (var match in matches) 
{
    //...
```

Assuming that the `var matches = results.ToList()` is very slow, I'd look at the functions in the `WHERE` clause

```
(a.CreateDt.HasValue &&
a.CreateDt >= Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.BeginDt) &&
a.CreateDt <= Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.EndDt))
```

to check that they aren't being executed for every row.

If you use SQL Server, run Profiler (in the Tools menu) to trace the SQL that LINQ-to-SQL.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, the problem was with the datetime evaluations. The linq query without the where clause is very quick.

Comment: @james31rock Good luck! If `CreateDt` is a function or computed column, you might want to persist it.

Answer (score 1):

And, of course, do the conversion outside the linq. criteria won't change
during the runtime of the Linq expression.

From what you posted, I made this example:

```
var begin = Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.BeginDt);
var end = Convert.ToDateTime(searchCriteria.EndDt);

var results = from a in searchList
              where ((a.CreateDt.HasValue &&
                      a.CreateDt >= begin &&
                      a.CreateDt <= end)
                      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.AgentNumber) || a.LgAgentNumber == searchCriteria.AgentNumber)
                      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.AgentTitle) || a.LgTitle == searchCriteria.AgentTitle)
                      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.QuotePolicyNumber) || a.LgTitle == searchCriteria.QuotePolicyNumber)
                      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchCriteria.InsuredName) || a.LgInsuredName.Contains(searchCriteria.InsuredName))
                     )
                        select a;
```

Perhaps this is helpful for you.

For measuring the time I used the following:

```
var watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();
var arr = results.ToArray();  // force evaluation of linq
watch.Stop();
var elapsed = watch.ElapsedTicks;
```

Seems the altered query is already about 30-40% faster on average, but i just
did some runs.

Comment: `Do not use Where if you do not absolutly have to. Use Join whenever possible.` Why?

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: The explanation can now be found in my answer.

Comment: The takeaway from that question is `avoid WHERE to specify relations and use JOIN whenever possible`. OP is not specifying a relation. I think you are misguided here - he is selecting from a single table, and `WHERE` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: This where vs. join is an awesome hint, but the select is on a single table so this does not apply here.

Comment: The Where vs Join is general information on how to improve performance. The answer I provided also uses where, but somewhat altered to OPs version. Where do you see that I'm misguided (except the first sentence)?

Comment: removed the hint on using Join. so please remove the -1.

Comment: @MareInfinitus `Where vs Join is general information` - no, only when actually joining / selecting from multiple tables. On a single table it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I do have another query that uses join, because I am selecting from multiple tables. With this query I am selecting from a view that already joins the tables, so no join is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest few experiments:

One.
Put a

```
int count = results.Count();
```

before the *foreach* and see if this takes a long time.

Two.
Leave the the *Count()* call and see if the *foreach* is still slow. If it is fast it would suggest that the initial connection to the db is slow.

As others suggested - have a look how you query performs in the db (actually type in in the database, without c#).

You could also post a SHOW TABLE result so the community could inspect the indexes and help you with a fix.

Comment: Please note that Count() has a shortcircuit on Lists. that may be a trap!

Comment: Thanks, The view by iteself. SELECT * FROM VIEW takes about 6 seconds. Adding the date range specification increases the time of the view to 1:32. I never had this problem with views before. I think its due to the number of records (84763) in the table that contains CreateDt.I need to modify my views so they are faster when searching between a date range.

Comment: I tested my Linq with DataSets with 100.000 entries. It went through the Where in no time (some milliseconds). What about using select * and doing the remaining in Linq? But, of course, something seems to be wrong with your view.